# datatables object of objects instead of array of objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, datatables

I'm very new to this whole area of js and datatables.

How can this be represented in datatables

```
var data = {"jaxm":
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect"
    },
    "jaxb" :
    {
     "name": "Garrett Winters",
     "position": "Accountant"
    }

}
```

I tried

```
$(duTable).DataTable({
    data:  data,
});
```

not sure if this possible without arrays or not but even I couldnt print single row in datatables using

```
$(duTable).DataTable({
    data:  data.jaxm,
});
```

Comment: What do you expect the table to look like for that sample input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot (the short answer). The above is more like a hash table, or a kind of associate array: You have an object with multiple keys (not indexes) each of them holding an object. You need to sanitize such construct into an indexed array :

```
function sanitizeData() {
  var d = [];
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    d.push(data[key]);
  });
  return d;
}

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  data:  sanitizeData(),
  // **and** instruct dataTables which object property belongs to which column
  columns: [
    { data: 'name' },
    { data: 'position' }
  ]
})
```

See demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0c52ra0c/**

It is basically just an algorithmic version of

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  data:  [data.jaxm, data.jaxb],
  columns: [
    { data: 'name' },
    { data: 'position' }
  ]
})
```

which would do the same. So you could use `data: [data.jaxm]` as a solution for the last attempt of "print single row". Either way, you need to pass an indexed array to dataTables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this does the job, but thinking of it... it's very weird that datatables don't allow using this kind of json data :S